# Binary Tree Python - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm trying to add elements to a binary tree and print them in pre-order.

The elements that are added to the binary tree are of type node.

I'm getting an error while adding an element:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'`

Please let me know where I have to make a change
Below is the code:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.item)


class BinaryTree(object):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def add(self, value):

        val = self.root
        if not val:
            val = value
        elif not val.left:
            val = value
        elif not val.right:
            val = value
        else:
            self.left = val.left.add(value)
        return val

    def preorder(self):
        val = self.root
        print(val)
        if val.left:
            val.left.preorder()
        if val.right:
            val.right.preorder()


def main():

    binary_tree = BinaryTree()

    print("Adding nodes in tree")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        node = Node(i)
        binary_tree.add(node)

    print("Printing preorder...")
    binary_tree.preorder()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Adding nodes in tree
Printing preorder...
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\binary_tree_test5.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\binary_tree_test5.py", line 49, in main
    binary_tree.preorder()
  File ".\binary_tree_test5.py", line 33, in preorder
    if val.left:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'
```

Comment: Please add full traceback to help debug error. Just adding type of error is not helpful.

Comment: How is `add()` supposed to add a node to the tree?

Comment: @Poojan - added full traceback

Comment: I'm trying to implement a binary tree, not binary search tree, and passing an object of type Node to the binary tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- in your code its the case when your root node is null.
- you can prevent this by checking root values.

```py
def preorder(self):
    val = self.root
    if not val: # this will handle the case when root node is None.
        return 
    print(val)
    if val.left:
        val.left.preorder()
    if val.right:
        val.right.preorder()
```

PS: I think your `add` method is wrong. You can debug that part for any other issues.

Comment: Thank you for your input, yes infact the add method is not working - while printing it just shows the first element. Should I post a different question for that or should I edit this question?

Answer (score 0):

`binary_tree = BinaryTree()` - `BinaryTree.__init__` has a default argument of `None` for the root parameter.  When you add a `Node` and check for the root, if it doesn't have one you should make one.

```
....
    def add(self, value):
        val = self.root
        if not val:
            self.root = value
            val = value
        ...
```

Or

```
....
    def add(self, value):    
        if not self.root:
            self.root = value
        val = self.root
        ...
```

This will solve the problem of having a `root` of `None` as long as you call `add` on an empty tree before you do anything else.

If you want to maintain the option of creating empty trees, you might consider [adding a meaningful Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) to methods that won't work for a rootless tree.

```
class RootLessException(Exception):
    pass
...
...
    def preorder(self):
        if not self.root:
            raise RootLessException
        val = self.root
        ...
```